# Windows Forms - Color on ListBox Items if meets SQL condition

Tags: c#, colors, conditional-statements, listbox

I want to change the color of the items of my `ListBox` that are meeting SQL condition, when the Forms is loaded.

Example :
I open the `FormsProducts`:
The A product has a MTBF value above 30 -> The item will be written normally in the `ListBox`.
The B product has a MTBF value == 30 or below -> The item will be written/coloured in yellow in the `ListBox`.
The C product has a MTBF value == 0 -> The item will be written/coloured in red in the `ListBox`.

Please help me.

I tried to make `ListView` instead of my `ListBox` but as I found the "transformation" difficult, I prefer to keep the `ListBox` as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, your question is about changing the color of list box items based on their `MTBF` property for a recordset returned by a SQL query. For purposes of a minimal example, let's say your record class is named `Product` and for testing purposes it will generate a random `MTBF` that is one of {0, 29, 30, or 31}. It will also have a `DisplayColor` property based on the `MTBF` property.

```
class Product
{
    static int _testCount = 0;
    static Random _rando = new Random(100);

    public string Name { get; set; } = $"Item {++_testCount}";
    public int MTBF { get; set; } = mockMTBF();
    public Color DisplayColor =>
        MTBF.Equals(0) ? Color.Red :
        MTBF <= 30 ? Color.YellowGreen : Color.Black;

    public override string ToString() => Name;

    private static int mockMTBF()
    {
        int randNext = _rando.Next(29, 33);
        switch (randNext)
        {
            case 29:
            case 30:
            case 31:
                return randNext;
            case 32:
                return 0;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Simulated SQL Query**

When the [Mock Query] button is clicked, five new Product records will be generated and placed in the list box.

[image: screenshot]

```
private void onClickMockQuery(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Product[] recordset =
        Enumerable.Range(0, 5)
        .Select(_ => new Product())
        .ToArray();

    listBox.Items.Clear();
    listBox.Items.AddRange(recordset);
}
```

---

**ListBox Owner Draw**

The main form ctor sets the `listBox.DrawMode` to `OwnerDrawFixed` and borrows from this Microsoft [code example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem) to render the text according to the `DisplayColor` property of `Product`.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox.DrawMode= DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        listBox.DrawItem += onDrawItem;
        buttonMockQuery.Click += onClickMockQuery;
    }

    private void onDrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((sender is ListBox listBox) && !e.Index.Equals(-1))
        {
            e.DrawBackground();
            Product product = (Product)listBox.Items[e.Index];
            using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(product.DisplayColor))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox.Items[e.Index].ToString(),
                    e.Font, brush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
            }
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: I'll take your example to see what happens, thank you very much for your quick and detailed answer ! I'll keep you informed.

Comment: Your answer was so clear that I managed to implement my idea, thank you :)